# Linear map - how to show this?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assuming that I have a map $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and we have $A(-x,x) = -A(x,x)$ and $A(x+y,x) = A(x,x)+ A(y,x)$. Is this sufficient to conclude that $A( \lambda x+y ,x ) = \lambda A(x,x)+ A(y,x)$?

Comment: does not look sufficient to me.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Assuming the axiom of choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation#Proof_of_the_existence_of_other_solutions), you would need additional hypothesis (such as the hypothesis that $A$ is continuous) in order to prove that $A$ is a linear map.

Outside of that, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: It seems to be that your example doesn't satisfy the second condition: $A(2+\sqrt2-\sqrt2,2+\sqrt 2)=2$, but $A(2+\sqrt 2,2+\sqrt 2)=0$, and $A(-\sqrt 2, 2+\sqrt 2)=0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @voldemort not missing anything; that was an oversight

Comment: I also think that additional hypothesis that $A$ is continuous is needed- but I am having trouble coming up with a counterexample. Essentially I think one should use the example of a map  $ T \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ but is not linear.

Comment: @voldemort apparently there's a bit of [axiom of choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation#Proof_of_the_existence_of_other_solutions) at work here